# Trying to stack several groups of columns into multiple target columns by name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the original dataframe like that which contains 1772 columns and 130 rows. I would like to stack them into multiple target columns.

| id | AA_F1R1 | BB_F1R1 | AA_F1R2 | BB_F1R2 | ... | AA_F2R1 | BB_F2R2 | ... | AA_F7R25 | BB_F7R25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 5 | xy | xx | xx | zy | 1 |  | 4 | xx |  |
| 002 | 6 | zzz | yyy | zzz | xw | 2 | zzz | 3 | zzz |  |

I found two different solutions that seem to work but for me is giving an error. Not sure if they work with NaN values.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['AA', 'BB'], i='id', j='dropme', sep='_')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('dropme', axis=1)\
  .sort_values('id')
Output:
0 rows × 1773 columns
```

Another solution I tried was

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(df.columns.str.split("_")))
df.stack(level = 1).reset_index(level = 1, drop = True).reset_index()

Output:
150677 rows × 2 columns
```

the problem with this last one is I couldn't keep the columns I wanted.

I appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `suffix=r'\w+'` parameter in [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['AA','BB'], i='id', j='dropme', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('dropme', axis=1)\
  .sort_values('id')
```

In second solution add `dropna=False` to [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
df = df.stack(level = 1, dropna=False).reset_index(level = 1, drop = True).reset_index()
```